# How would I request extended persmissions on FaceBook login

Tags: facebook

I tried:

```
<fb:login-button v="2" perms="email"></fb:login-button>
```

But when the FaceBook login window pops up, I don't see the extended permission, only the basic.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that it already granted you this permission once? It wouldn't show dialog twice. Try to remove this app from your installed apps and test again.

You can also trigger login dialog using [javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login).